# Reduce size of responsive title

Tags: php, css, title, responsive

When using a mobile device or a tablet, the titles of my products are cropped. I'd like to simply reduce their size. Take a look to the image:[image: Cropped title]

Is there a way to change that? Is it CSS or Php?

The URL of the product is this: https://www.editorialufv.es/catalogo/territory-inhabited/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom CSS where you use media query in order to reduce the font-size of the title in small devices. You also have some styling that remove the **line break** and add the **3 dots** at the end. So you can also remove them.

You can try this code :

```
@media all and (max-width:480px) {
  .woocommerce div.product .product_title {
    font-size:18px;
    white-space: initial;
    text-overflow: initial;
  }
}
```

You may adjust the value of font-size as you need.

Comment: Great, but is there a way to not cropping the title? For instance, making it on two or more lines?

Comment: @Stefano yes, simply remove the font size and keep the two other styles ... these style will for ce title to go into multi line